# How to know where water from gutters is going?

Tags: water, pipe, drainage, gutters

My gutters are connected to pipes that go underground. I am trying to figure out where these pipes are connected to ,and ultimately where is the water going.

The previous owners didn't give me any information, and I want to understand what my drainage system looks like.

How can one figure out where the water is going to? I tried hosing the pipe connected to the gutter with water and see if I see any stream of water coming out at the end of the backyard, but no luck.

Comment: Is this an urban or rural setting?

Comment: Use a camera. They make camera systems for plumbing diagnostics, they’re expensive but you can always get an inexpensive one online.

Comment: Urban setting...

Comment: Is this just a curiosity question, or are you having problems that may indicate a blockage?  If it's the later, then a plumber or drain cleaning company can come out with their camera system and assess the situation.

Comment: SteveSh - I am building a french drain, and wanted to see if I could connect it to the existing underground pipes that comes from the gutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an urban setting, there are two likely places a downspout drain would go.

1. To the street curb
2. Into a storm drain system (or in many older cities the sewage system)

The street curb option is pretty easy to verify by doing as you did and running water into it and see if it is coming out somewhere at the street. The storm drain probably requires a camera that is meant to snake through pipes.

There are plenty of other possibilities, but in a city become less likely.

In any case, using a plumbing camera is the best way to know for sure as well as inspect for damage. This also has the added benefit of having a way to look at the plumbing inside the house as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Non-toxic septic dye** is helpful if trying to trace water flow. But you still may not see it if it goes somewhere and soaks away (or goes to a storm sewer if urban), rather than "coming out" - the the dye will make it VERY obvious if it **does** come out.